# how to change bios mode from legacyto UEFI mode?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

Currently, my operating system is windows 10. I want to dual boot ubuntu and windows 10. Since the current drive didn’t have enough space I added another ssd drive. When I was installing ubuntu, I noticed that the other os was not recognized. I checked my UEFI Boot setting, as it is shown in the following picture, it is enable. Besides, secure mode is not supported.
[image]

I don’t know why in “system information” the BIOS mode is still “Legacy”. Here is system information window:

[image]

Could you tell what I should do? My laptop model is asus n53sv (I have been using it since 2011).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu supports *secure-boot* uEFI so are you saying windows 10 doesn't support it; you're wrong there I gather; is it your hardware that doesn't support *secure-boot*? as its unclear as its unclear to me. Ubuntu does **not** require uEFI or Secure-uEFI (*secure boot*) so if its not supported by your box it won't be an issue, but you should install Ubuntu is exactly the same mode as your existing windows, and ensure *fastboot* or *hibernate* are disabled on windows. Also write the ISO correctly to media; as some write methods prevent Secure-uEFI from working (*clone* write is best).